# What is causing this "jpackage does not exist" error?

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, jpackage

I'm trying to make an installer from my Gradle + JavaFX project using jpackage but the following error occurs:

```
Execution failed for task ':jpackageImage'.
> /home/jonander/.gradle/daemon/6.8/null/bin/jpackage does not exist.
```

This is my `module.info`:

```java
module Seftic.main {
    requires java.sql;
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
}
```

This is my configuration in `build.gradle`:

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.24.1'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.10'
}

javafx {
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml','javafx.base' ]
}
```

What is causing this error, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: The `null` in the path suggests that something went wrong when constructing the path to the binary. What JDK are you running this in?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if anyone found a better solution but, you could set `jpackageHome` to your JDK install, in your `build.gradle`:

```
jlink {
    jpackage {
        jpackageHome = '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home'
        installerType = 'dmg'
    }
}
```